# how to find the documentation or examples of a library RAE?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I found this library of the Royal Academy of the Spanish language.

[image]

https://pypi.org/project/rae/

I have installed it with the command:

```
 pip install rae
```

but I just don't know how to use it, does anyone know how I can make it work with some basic command? like:

```
>>exact('hola')
```

Comment: Try using `help(exact)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
import rae
print(rae.DLE.exact('hola'))
```

Comment: I am getting error for example with import rae
print( rae.DLE.anagrams("hola"))   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rae\__init__.py", line 65, in get_payload
    first = re.search('document\.forms\[0\]\.elements\[1\]\.value=\"(.+?):', r).group(1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: That means the `exact` method of the class `DLE ` is being called. Internal code of the `exact` method is throwing this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin `help` in Python interpreter.

```
>>>>import rae
>>>>help(rae)

Help on package rae:

NAME
    rae - # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

FILE
    /home/sahil/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rae/__init__.py

PACKAGE CONTENTS


CLASSES
    __builtin__.object
        Article
        DA
        DEJ
        DLE
        DPD

    class Article(__builtin__.object)
     |  Methods defined here:
     |
```

Comment: I am getting error for example with import rae
print( rae.DLE.anagrams("hola"))   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rae\__init__.py", line 65, in get_payload
    first = re.search('document\.forms\[0\]\.elements\[1\]\.value=\"(.+?):', r).group(1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: I am sorry my friend but you're gonna have to google your way out of that. I am not familiar with `rae` and the pypi page seems to be in spanish, which I can't read.